# Error CS1519 - Invalid token 'float' in class, struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, interface, declaration

I am creating an asteroid shooting game, and I am doing homework for class to add a score. After adding "scoreValue" and "playerScript" to the Asteroid script,

I now get "Error CS1519 - Invalid token 'float' in class, struct or interface member declaration"

Here is my current code with the error:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class asteroidScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform explosion;
    private asteroidScript scriptAsteroid;
    public int scoreValue;
    public playerScript 

    //my screen size limits
    float minX = -12.72f,
         maxX = 12.72f,
         minY = -11.89f,
         maxY = 11.89f;
    float startY, endY;
    private int newScoreValue;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startY = maxY + 3; //initializing start point for asteroid
        endY = minY + -3; // initializing end point for asteroid
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //check if I passed the bottom of the screen
        if (transform.position.y < minY)
        {
            //function call
            resetEnemy();
        }

    }

    public void resetEnemy()
    {
        //Reset the position of the asteriods
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.y = startY;
        //randomly choose my x position
        position.x = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
        //put the asteroid at that position
        transform.position = position;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        //I am going to check what I collided with
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid")
        {
            //Reposition the asteroid to the top of the game
            //get the asteriod Script
            scriptAsteroid = other.GetComponent<asteroidScript>();
            //call the function to reset asteroid
            scriptAsteroid.resetEnemy();
            //create explosion
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //reset myself - the asteroid
            resetEnemy();
        }
        //I am going to check if I collided with the player
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //create explosion
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //reset myself - the asteroid
            resetEnemy();
            //later I have to code the shield in :)
        }
      { 
        playerScript.AddScore(newScoreValue);
}
    }
}
```

And here is what my code looked like with no errors before making changes...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class asteroidScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform explosion;
    private asteroidScript scriptAsteroid;
    //my screen size limits
    float minX = -12.72f,
         maxX = 12.72f,
         minY = -11.89f,
         maxY = 11.89f;
    float startY, endY;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startY = maxY + 3; //initializing start point for asteroid
        endY = minY + -3; // initializing end point for asteroid
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //check if I passed the bottom of the screen
        if (transform.position.y < minY)
        {
            //function call
            resetEnemy();
        }

    }

    public void resetEnemy()
    {
        //Reset the position of the asteriods
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.y = startY;
        //randomly choose my x position
        position.x = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
        //put the asteroid at that position
        transform.position = position;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        //I am going to check what I collided with
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid")
        {
            //Reposition the asteroid to the top of the game
            //get the asteriod Script
            scriptAsteroid = other.GetComponent<asteroidScript>();
            //call the function to reset asteroid
            scriptAsteroid.resetEnemy();
            //create explosion
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //reset myself - the asteroid
            resetEnemy();
        }
        //I am going to check if I collided with the player
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //create explosion
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //reset myself - the asteroid
            resetEnemy();
            //later I have to code the shield in :)
        }
    }
}
```

I fail to see what went wrong, and why "Float" is now declared an invalid token. Any solutions would be most helpful! Thank you!

- Justin

Comment: `public playerScript` -- missing semicolon. If you ever get an "unexpected blah blah" error, look for a missing semicolon on the line before.

Comment: Thank you! I am such an amateur and often fail to see the most simple changes. Coding is not my forte. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are missing semicolon after `public playerScript`

Comment: Don't worry about it - it's a knack. After a while you start to see punctuation that isn't there. Unfortunately I don't think it's a transferable skill...

Answer (score 0):

you should use a **";"** in line 9  after declaring "public playerScript "
it's a common missing Semicolon
I know its late but I hope Someone else can use this